# Change Internet Explorer's interface

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, themes, user-interface

I don't like Internet Explorer 8's default interface. Does IE8 on Windows 7 support any sort of user-created themes or skins?

Comment: This question was likely to be closed for being subjective. I edited it to be less so, and make it into a more useful question. If you have any questions, feel free to comment.

Comment: Theme/skin support is what programmers build when they run out of ideas for _real_ features

Comment: Bah, expecting Microsoft to be in the 21st century, LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [IE9 beta](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/download/ie-9/worldwide). I don't think it has skin support either, but it is different from IE8.

Comment: IE9 feels better than IE8.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer does not have any built-in official skinning or theme-creating capabilities.  If you want to change how things look in your browser, you would be better off using a more customizable browser, like Firefox (which has themes that affect the entire layout and personas which just change the colors/images), or Chrome (which has different style themes, but you can't change the layout).

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

Just visit http://google.com/chrome and and install the new GUI from there. ;)

You will notice that it will be faster too.

Comment: And I can run ActiveX components in it.

Comment: @Steve: Why do you need to run ActiveX components? If it's for work, then just use IE for work and Chrome or another browser for casual browsing. You shouldn't care how your browser looks for work.